# Passing an integer into javascript from applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

im trying to pass an integer into an execute javascript statement to use as the index of an array in the javascript. Is this possible and if so how?

```
set i to 0
tell active tab of win 
    set failedTests to (execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('specDetail failed')[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].title") as string                  
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set i to 0
set jsCommand to "document.getElementsByClassName('specDetail failed')[" & i & "].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].title"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1
        set xxx to execute javascript jsCommand
    end tell
end tell
```